# Rounding numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby

I take 8 variables and find the average. I did it using `to_f` to make them numbers that can have decimals. I need it to be rounded to the nearest tenth. For example, the number can be 3.875, and I need it to be rounded to 3.9. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `3.875.round(1) #=> 3.9` – did you read the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-round)? ;-)

Comment: Wow. No, I am using codecademy as well with searching questions I have on google. Thank you for showing me this though, I will make sure to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [round method.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-round)  It takes an integer parameter specifying the number of decimals you want to round to.

```
NUMBER_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES_TO_ROUND_TO = 1    
rounded_mean = your_calculated_mean.round(NUMBER_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES_TO_ROUND_TO)
```

Check out [this article on Rounding Numbers in Ruby](https://richonrails.com/articles/rounding-numbers-in-ruby)